# Text align center buttons

Tags: html, css, position, text-align

I need to center buttons in the middle of page, one under another.

I've used code below, but the result was that buttons still appear next to each other.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  .btn {
    @include Myriad-Pro-Light;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
  }
  .btn-green {
    color: #fff;
    background: #7CAE9E;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .btn-grey {
    color: #333;
    background: $grey;
    margin: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-green" role="button">Button A</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-grey" role="button">Button B</a>
</header>
```

Thank you

Comment: Guys - really consider what the code is before you make it into a runnable snippet. If the CSS needs to be run through a preprocessor before it can be used, then it's not runnable.

Comment: Put a `<br>` between them?

Answer (score 0):

you can use "flexbox" for this

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
    .btn {
        @include Myriad-Pro-Light;
        border-radius: 7px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: none;
    }

    .btn-green {
        color: #fff;
        background: #7CAE9E;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    .btn-grey {
        color: #333;
        background: $grey;
        margin: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-green" role="button">a</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-grey" role="button">b</a>
    </header>
```

Without flexbox

```css
.btn {
  @include Myriad-Pro-Light;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-green {
  color: #fff;
  background: #7CAE9E;
  margin: 20px;
}
.btn-grey {
  color: #333;
  background: $grey;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-green" role="button">a</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-grey" role="button">b</a>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid that flex will not work on older browsers, like IE
do you have any other solution ?

Comment: @JZK Just how far back in browser compatibility are you going? That could drastically affect potential answers.

Comment: IE 8 will be nice to have supported, everything above is fine.
but if the solution have to be way to complicated, we can skip IE support. Well, in worst case the buttons will be still visible.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** check new fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bimbonkens/fa7s3ypj/

you needed only the

```
display:block
```

on your buttons.

also your css syntax is wrong for vanilla css(no preprocessors)

```
header {
  .btn {}
}
```

should be this

```
header {    }
.btn {    }
```

and if you need context:

```
header {}
header .btn {}
```

You need to use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

for block elements, because

```
text-align:center;
```

works only on inline and inline-block

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I'm ussing SCSS

That's the thing, when I've used display block, it stretch buttons on whole width of the page. 
I don't need that

Comment: ok, anyways you should learn about block, inline, inline-block and other element types.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you want something like this:-**

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  .btn {
    @include Myriad-Pro-Light;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
  }
  .btn-green {
    color: #fff;
    background: #7CAE9E;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .btn-grey {
    color: #333;
    background: $grey;
    margin: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-green" role="button">Button A</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-grey" role="button">Button B</a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to go could be the following:

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}
  header .btn {
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .btn-green {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #7CAE9E;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .btn-grey {
    color: #333;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-green" role="button">Button A</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-grey" role="button">Button B</a>
</header>
```